# mov and mp4 files to play in browser

Tags: php, html, video, ffmpeg

Currently I am playing with html5 video tag and database video files. I have couple of records in database that contains mov & mp4 files. HTML5 video tag supports mp4 but what about mov files ? I am trying to use external libraries but it not helps .. might be my implementation is wrong ...

Can we get any library that converts mov to mp4 or browser that support ONLINE rather than saving it anywhere ... ?

Also can I get any code snippet for handbrake source code implementation so that I can try for it.

Comment: step 1) google. step 2) attempt. step 3) post your code on stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like these..

```
<video id="sampleMovie" src="HTML5Sample.mov"></video>
```

and

```
<video id="sampleMovie" width="640" height="360" preload controls>
    <source src="HTML5Sample_H264.mov" />
    <source src="HTML5Sample_Ogg.ogv" />
    <source src="HTML5Sample_WebM.webm" />
</video>
```

Comment: Can it play mov file on windows ? As per my knowledge Quicktime required to play mov files on browser.

Comment: Indeed, assuming your server allows .mov mime file types. Mind you .mov is a container format-not a codec. if the mov files are encoded in .h264, they will work. Mov and Mp4 files are usually the standard not problematic like wmv files ;)